# Vercel storage for serverless functions python

Tags: python, storage, serverless, vercel

I am trying to explore serverless functions with the twitter api and I am working with vercel. My first project is really simple, just consisting in a python script with the function code and a json file that acts like a database (ommiting requirements.txt and other neccessary files). My goal is to get a twitter account publish a post everyday at the same time, containing the next element from the database next to the last posted one. For this purpose I have to fields in my json that I wanted to update everyday, they are 2 number fields storaging the last id posted and the last day posted, but I have found that in vercel is not possible to write files, just read them.

I have also found that in the same project there are some kind of storage avaliable, but I do not get to understand them properly and link with my function.

Any orientation or hint on how to do it would be welcome,
thank you for reading.